# Sequelize migration add "IF NOT EXISTS" to addIndex and addColumn

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

**Is there a way to force Sequelize.js to add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the Postgres SQL created by the `queryInterface.addColumn` and `queryInterface.addIndex` methods?**

According to the Postgres Docs this is supported for [Alter Table Add Column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html) as well as [Create Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createindex.html)

I have looked through the Sequelize.js docs without any luck, and I have tried to go through the code to figure out how the SQL is generated, but I have not had any luck yet.

---

#### A bit of background, or "Why"

I am trying to create a migration strategy for an existing postgres instance, and I have currently created a Sequelize migration set which migrates from "nothing" to the current schema. Now I would like to simply get this up and running on my production server where all of the data already exists such that the next time I create a migration, I can run it.

All of this works well for every `queryInterface.createTable` because the `IF NOT EXISTS` is automatically added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`addColumn` function comes from `queryGenerator` method called [`addColumnQuery`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/dialects/postgres/query-generator.js#L238), which accepts three parameters - `table`, `key` and `dataType`. With use of them it creates a query, which looks like that

```
let query = `ALTER TABLE ${quotedTable} ADD COLUMN ${quotedKey} ${definition};`;
```

So, as you can see, there is no option to add the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause to the query string. The same concerns the `addIndex` method unfortunately. However, you can use plain query in order to perform some atypical operations

```
queryInterface.sequelize.query(...);
```

Comment: Yeah, I found that code looking through the repo myself. I am considering creating a PR on the repo to enable this functionality, however what I ended up doing is to manually update the `SequelizeMeta` to fake the running of the migrations.

Comment: @Cort3z did you ever end up doing a PR for this?

Comment: @Simon I never did. Was a fire-and-forget job for me. I don't quite remember, but I might have manually updated my database with PSequel, or some other db management tool.

Comment: @Cort3z Yeah, I just ended up going with a raw query that checks for existing indexes. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue, except in my case I was only interested in addColumn IF NOT EXIST.

You can achieve this with a two step solution, using `queryInterface.describeTable`.
Given the table name the function will return the table definition which contains all the existing columns. If the column you need to add does not exist then call the `queryInterface.addColumn` function.

```
const tableName = 'your_table_name';

queryInterface.describeTable(tableName)
  .then(tableDefinition => {
    if (tableDefinition.yourColumnName) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      tableName,
      'your_column_name',
      { type: Sequelize.STRING } // or a different column
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

The statement `if (!tableDefinition.yourColumnName)` won't be able to check if column exists. 
Correct way is

```
return queryInterface.describeTable(tableName).then(tableDefinition => {
            if (!tableDefinition[columnName]){
                return queryInterface.addColumn(tableName, columnName, {
                    type: Sequelize.JSON
                });
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what I needed

Answer (score 6):

A small working example:

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * @description Up.
   * @param {QueryInterface} queryInterface
   * @return Promise<void>
   */
  up: async (queryInterface) => {
    const tableDefinition =  await queryInterface.describeTable('group');
    const promises = [];

    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction((transaction) => {
      if (!tableDefinition.column1) {
        promises.push(queryInterface.addColumn(
          'group',
          'column1',
          {
            type: queryInterface.sequelize.Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
          },
          {transaction},
        ));
      }

      if (!tableDefinition.oauth2_token_expire_at) {
        promises.push(queryInterface.addColumn(
          'group',
          'column2',
          {
            type: queryInterface.sequelize.Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
          },
          {transaction},
        ));
      }

      return Promise.all(promises);
    });
  },
  /**
   * @description Down.
   * @param {QueryInterface} queryInterface
   * @return Promise<void>
   */
  down: (queryInterface) => {
    ...
  },
};
```